# Live USB with custom CentOS image and Veracrypt Partition

Tags: linux, centos, partition, live-usb, dracut

### Context:

I have a USB drive with 2 partitions: the first one is a custom, non-persistent, image of CentOS 7.6 1810 (with GNOME) and the second one is an encrypted data partition. The objective is to have a bootable live CentOS USB drive from which a user can then load the encrypted partition to store his/her files. And for the most part, everything is working as expected. The generated ISO works perfectly with VirtualBox and never had any issue with the ISO. The issue appears when I combine the CentOS live USB partition with the data partition on the USB drive.

### Problem:

When I boot the USB, I *sometimes* gets the following error:

```
dracut: FATAL: Failed to mount block device of live image
dracut: Refusing to continue
system halted.
```

Note that in many cases, I can successfully have the live CentOS image loaded without any error. So this is a probabilistic issue, implying a potential race condition involve somewhere.

I've enabled the debugging options for `dracut` to output a log file on boot, the issue met appears to be highlighted with the following lines:

```
[    4.015983] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + CMDLINE='   initrd=initrd0.img root=live:CDLABEL=CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810 rootfstype=auto ro rd.live.image rd.shell rd.debug log_buf_len=1M rd.luks=0 rd.md=0 rd.dm=0 BOOT_IMAGE=vmlinuz0'
[    4.016557] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.017178] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.017761] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.018361] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.018951] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.019579] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.020202] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.020785] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.021363] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + liverw=ro
[    4.021952] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.022584] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.023205] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.023798] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.024390] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.024970] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.025584] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.026135] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.026745] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.027375] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.027941] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.028544] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.029125] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.029652] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.030241] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + for arg in '$CMDLINE'
[    4.030788] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + case $arg in
[    4.031377] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + mkdir -m 0755 -p /run/initramfs/live
[    4.031924] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + '[' -f /dev/sda2 ']'
[    4.032484] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: ++ blkid -o value -s TYPE /dev/sda2
[    4.033075] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + '[' '' '!=' ntfs ']'
[    4.033564] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + mount -n -t auto -o ro /dev/sda2 /run/initramfs/live
[    4.034100] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
[    4.034593] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: missing codepage or helper program, or other error
[    4.035175] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
[    4.035726] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: dmesg | tail or so.
[    4.036299] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + '[' 32 '!=' 0 ']'
[    4.036846] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + die 'Failed to mount block device of live image'
[    4.037422] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + echo '<24>dracut: FATAL: Failed to mount block device of live image'
[    4.037966] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + echo '<24>dracut: Refusing to continue'
[    4.038553] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + echo 'warn dracut: FATAL: "Failed to mount block device of live image"'
[    4.039143] localhost dracut-initqueue[773]: + echo 'warn dracut: Refusing to continue'
```

Based on the output above, `dracut` appears to be trying to load the live image from `/dev/sda2`, which is the data partition, not the CentOS one and thus fails to boot. In other words, `dracut` sometimes uses the proper partition - `/dev/sda1` - to boot the OS, but for some reason, sometimes tries to use `/dev/sda2`. Trying to replace the `root` parameter with `root=/dev/sda1` didn't worked.

Running `blkid` at the `dracut` shell yields:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="2019-07-06-19-24-46-00" LABEL="CentOS-7-x86_x64-LiveGNOME-1810" TYPE="iso9660" PTTYPE="dos"
```

However, looking at the log generated by `dracut`, I can see the following output:

```
+ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="2019-07-06-19-24-46-00" LABEL="CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810" TYPE="iso9660" PTTYPE="dos" 
+ blkid -o udev
ID_FS_UUID=2019-07-06-19-24-46-00
ID_FS_UUID_ENC=2019-07-06-19-24-46-00
ID_FS_LABEL=CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810
ID_FS_LABEL_ENC=CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810
ID_FS_TYPE=iso9660
ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
+ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id /dev/disk/by-label /dev/disk/by-path /dev/disk/by-uuid
/dev/disk/by-id:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 0  9 Jul  7 11:54 usb-SanDisk_Extreme_Pro_00000000000000000000-0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 0 10 Jul  7 11:54 usb-SanDisk_Extreme_Pro_00000000000000000000-0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 0 10 Jul  7 11:54 usb-SanDisk_Extreme_Pro_00000000000000000000-0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2

/dev/disk/by-label:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 0 10 Jul  7 11:54 CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810 -> ../../sda2

/dev/disk/by-path:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 0  9 Jul  7 11:54 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 0 10 Jul  7 11:54 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 0 10 Jul  7 11:54 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2

/dev/disk/by-uuid:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 0 10 Jul  7 11:54 2019-07-06-19-24-46-00 -> ../../sda2
```

I have no idea why the label *CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810* would be assigned to `sda2`.

### Question:

Is there a fix to ensure that the proper partition is always selected to guarantee a 100% success rate on boot? Right now, I have to power off the laptop, and repower it on until I can boot into the OS.

### Update:

This issue appears to be cause by having 2 partitions: the first one being the CentOS image and the second being an encrypted partition. While I can't fully explain the why, it seems that at boot, the label of the first partition, i.e `CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810` is assigned to the second partition as well. As such, when the boot sequence seeks the partition with the `CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810` label, it will return the first or second partition depending on which ever one comes first. This cause the key to some boot, when the first partition is selected first, and fail when the second one is returned.

I've tried changing the label of the second, Veracrypt-encrypted partition, but to no avail. I partially solved the issue by changing the root command to:

`initrd=initrd0.img root=live:/dev/sdb1 rootfstype=auto ro rd.live.image rd.shell rd.debug log_buf_len=1M rd.luks=0 rd.md=0 rd.dm=0 BOOT_IMAGE=vmlinuz0`

However this cause the USB key to fail on other devices. 
I have tried using `root=live:/dev/disk/by-id/usb-SanDisk_Extreme_Pro_00000000000000000000-0:0-part1` but that didn't seem to work either.

If anyone has any tips to help me out having a dual-partition, custom CentOS 7.6 image collocated with a Veracrypt partition that could work on most modern laptops/desktops, I would really appreciate it. Ideally working with EFI. Right now, I'll be happy with MBR.